# Inserir imagem no corpo do email

Tags: c#, smtp

Como faço para inserir uma imagem no corpo do e-mail utilizando C# ? Já consegui enviar como anexo mas gostaria de saber como proceder para enviá-la no corpo do email , tem algo que possibilite isso ?

Comment: Coloca o código de como você está gerando o e-mail, aí conseguiremos ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Faça com que seu e-mail seja enviado como HTML.

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<p>Veja essa imagem</p> <br/><br/><img src=\"cid:localDaImagem\" />"
```

Comment: acho que não precisa declarar a tag html e body, o proprio email ja identifica quando envia tag's html para ela

Comment: Provavelmente não precisa mesmo, não posso testar agora. Quando eu tiver certeza altero a resposta.

Comment: Eu tenho, olhe a fonte que coloquei na minha resposta.

Comment: Não que eu esteja duvidando de você, mas a locaweb é uma péssima fonte pra esse tipo de informação.

Comment: Mais lá foi o único lugar que eu encontrei no que deve-se usar ou nao de HTML e ainda fala algumas diferenças entre serviços de e-mails que tem que fazer alterações nas tag's do HTML. Caso ache uma fonte mais segura, coloque pra gente, a comunidade agradece e eu também. :D

Answer (score 2):

Onde você coloca o `body` do email, você irá atribuir tags `HTML`. Exemplo:

```
myMessage.message = "<img src='caminho_da_imagem' alt='Imagem' />"
```

Estou usando o `myMessage.message` como se fosse o parametro do corpo do email que você está enviando.

O [Wiki do LocaWeb](http://wiki.locaweb.com/pt-br/Boas_pr%C3%A1ticas_de_HTML_para_Email) da algumas dicas do que você deve utilizar para estes tipos de emails.